# Using find and map together React

Tags: reactjs

We have chat app build on React

```
const Chat = ({ thread }) => {
  return (
    <div className='thread'>
      {thread.map((message, index) =>
          <Message message={message} key={index} repliedMessage={message}/>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    thread: [
      {
        id: 1,
        user: 'John',
        text: 'Hellow'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        user: 'Jim',
        replyTo: 1,
        text: 'Hi'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        user: 'Jack',
        replyTo: 2,
        text: 'Cheers :)'
      }
    ]
  };
```

App must show what message have been replied.
The question is - how I can use FIND method with MAP in Chat component?

Comment: You need array of elements which have been replied to ? For example in this case [id:1, id:2 ] Objects right ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use the find method here:

```
thread.map((message, index) => {
   if(message.replyTo) {

           return ...

      } else {

           return ...

      }
   }
)
```